# react-redux-form - dispatch is not passed in props

Tags: forms, reactjs, redux

I am using [react-redux-forms](https://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/) and following [quick start](https://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/docs/guides/quickstart.html) I created react components:

This class containts store defintion and Provider

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore,applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { combineForms } from 'react-redux-form';
import RecordForm from './components/RecordForm.jsx'

    const initRecord= {
        name: '',
        SUKL: '',
        ATC: ''
    };

    const store = createStore(combineForms({
        record: initRecord
    }));

    @translate(['record'], { wait: true })
    export default class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }


    render() {
        const { t }= this.props;
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="row header">
                            <h1>
                                {t('record.NewRecord')}
                            </h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className="row">
                        <Provider store={ store }>
                            <RecordForm />
                        </Provider>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
```

This is form file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Control, Form } from 'react-redux-form';


export default class RecordForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    handleSubmit(record) {
        const { dispatch } = this.props;
        ///dispatch is undefined !!!!!!!
    }

    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <Form model="record"  onSubmit={(record) => this.handleSubmit(record)}>
                        <Control.text model="record.name"  />
               <button type="submit">
                 OK!
                </button>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }

}
```

When I get to handleSumbit part - **dispatch is undefined**. When I debug this, even in construtor of RecordForm there is n**o dispatch in props or anything releated to form**. Should I add some annotation like connect() ? What did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to connect your component using `connect()` function. As mentioned in [react-redux docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#inject-just-dispatch-and-dont-listen-to-store), You can just use `connect()` without any arguments.

Quoting from the provided link:

> **Inject just dispatch and don't listen to store**
>
> export default connect()(TodoApp)

But, if you are providing your custom `mapDispatchToProps` function as argument, dispatch won't be provided to you. If you still want it available as props, you will need to return it explicitly yourself in your `mapDispatchToProps` implementation. You can read about it in [FAQ Section](http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/ReactRedux.html#react-props-dispatch) at react-redux.

Also, If you want to try experimental `decorator` feature, you can use it using babel. In that case, you can connect your component using `@connect` as follows.

```
@connect()
export default class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  // ... your code goes here.
}
```